# Xamarin - Json Deserialization not working on exported Android apk

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I have a project with a User model class that has 4 object lists (Ambiente, Empresa, Filial e Projeto).
When I get the Json data from a webservice (using Newtonsoft.Json), the json code is correct, but when deserializing these lists of objects, they always came out null in the User class.
After setting the link to SDK Only, using [Preserve (AllMembers = true)], when running the project in Release and Debug, deserialization works correctly.

I've also added this in android MainActivity, in the OnCreate method:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        if (falseFlag) {
            var falseJC = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.BinaryConverter();
        }
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
```

This is the User class, and the objects list:

```
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
        public class Usuario
        {
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public int SessionId { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
            public int FilialId { get; set; }
            public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
            public DateTime DataLogin { get; set; }
            public object Matricula { get; set; }
            public object Server { get; set; }
            public string Senha { get; set; }
            public string Ambiente { get; set; }
            public string Idioma { get; set; }
            public string Device { get; set; }
            public string Acesso { get; set; }
            public string AmbienteSelecionado { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AMBIENTES")]
            public List Ambientes { get; set; }

            public List Empresas { get; set; }
            public List Filiais { get; set; }
            public List Projetos { get; set; }
        }

        [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
        public class Ambiente
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SGENVIRONMENT")]
            public string AmbienteId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DSENVIRONMENT")]
            public string AmbienteNome { get; set; }
        }

        [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
        public class Empresa
        {
            public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
            public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
        }

        [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
        public class Filial
        {
            public int FilialId { get; set; }
            public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
            public string Titulo { get; set; }
        }

        [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
        public class Projeto
        {
            public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
            public string Titulo { get; set; }
            public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
            public int FilialId { get; set; }
        }
```

And this is where the json is deserialized:

```
    Usuario jsonUsuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.message.ToString());
```

A week ago, before even doing this code, the deserialization worked. Then it suddenly stopped working on any situation, without changing any code.
Then I made all these changes above, making the deserialization work on Release / Debug on Visual Studio, but when exporting the apk and running it, the objects are still Null.

When using a TraceWriter to intercept the deserialization, the log shows this:

```
2020-06-04T18:03:27.142 Info Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'Ambientes' on Gestor_Coletor_A.Models.Usuario. Path 'Ambientes', line 1, position 289.

2020-06-04T18:03:27.161 Info Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'Empresas' on Gestor_Coletor_A.Models.Usuario. Path 'Empresas', line 1, position 560.

2020-06-04T18:03:27.171 Info Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'Filiais' on Gestor_Coletor_A.Models.Usuario. Path 'Filiais', line 1, position 838.

2020-06-04T18:03:27.182 Info Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'Projetos' on Gestor_Coletor_A.Models.Usuario. Path 'Projetos', line 1, position 1100.
```

Why the object lists are considered "non-writable property"? They are all public, no private variable is being used.
What I'm doing wrong?
I must make it work on exported apk.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you specify the type of List? Something like `public List<Ambientes> Ambientes { get; set; }`

Comment: First of all, Please copy your Json content to this url https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp, this tool will convert your Json data to C# model. please check your C# model, if it is correctly. If not, Please provide a  simple Json data, I can test it.